# Numpy 1d array to 2d array with first element being isolated

Tags: python, numpy

I start with something like

```
x = np.array([[5, 1, 2, 3, 4], [6, 2, 4, 6, 8]])
```

what I want is something like:

```
x = np.array([5, [[1, 2], [3, 4]], [6, [[2, 4],[6, 8]] ]
```

I currently have something

```
y = np.array([x[0][0], x[0][1:]], [x[1][0], x[1][1:]])
```

Comment: I would just split it into two arrays.  Numpy isn't meant to handle jagged shapes

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing []

```
x = np.array([[5, 1, 2, 3, 4], [6, 2, 4, 6, 8]])
```

With a list comprehension

```
[[row[0],row[1:].reshape(2,2).tolist()] for row in x]
```